# Changing file that torch is looking at in atom

Tags: python, julia, atom-editor, pytorch

I am trying to run some deep learning experiments to learn more about the subject and I am using atom as my editor. In the code I am trying to execute, I am loading some dataset from pytorch. For some reason, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
    File "D:\Julio\Documents\Michigan_v2\CS\EECS_598_Deep_Learning\HW\Homework2\blah.py", line 32, in <module>
    for x in ['train', 'val']}
  File "D:\Julio\Documents\Michigan_v2\CS\EECS_598_Deep_Learning\HW\Homework2\blah.py", line 32, in <dictcomp>
    for x in ['train', 'val']}
  File "C:\Users\Julio\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 178, in __init__
    target_transform=target_transform)
  File "C:\Users\Julio\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 75, in __init__
    classes, class_to_idx = find_classes(root)
  File "C:\Users\Julio\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py", line 23, in find_classes
    classes = [d for d in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, d))]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'hymenoptera_data\\train'
```

It seems to me that atom is looking for the files to load in a julia folder, but I don't know why atom is doing that and I don't know how to change it. Can anybody give me any suggestions on how to fix this?
THanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One of your code files, probably `folder.py` has changed your directory to look for files in that filepath: `hymenoptera_data\\train` as we can infer from

```
classes = [d for d in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, d))]
```

If this is intended behavior, consider fixing the filepath name to `hymenoptera_data\train`.
If this is not intended behavior, consider fixing the `folder.py` to not look for that.

Beyond that, it is impossible to know where's your error origin without looking at the code and your folder structure